# Statistics of 150 variables in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have tow data frames, one with 181 obs., and 521 variables, and the other data frame with two variables and 150 obs. The first data frame is the completely data, and the second is the continuos variables names from the first data frame. I want to calculate the mean, variance, median and other statistics for the continuos variables. For example:

```
df1:
    ha_be    me_cu    par_pri    fer_ex
      1      1000       300         5
      0      500        150         7
      0      300        400         5
      0      900         80         6
      1      2100        50         3
      1      3400        60         2
      0      390        800         1
      1      400        750         4

df_cont: 
      Cod    variable.names
      3.2     me_cu
      3.3     par_pri
```

How can I extract all the continuos variables from `df1`using the names in `df_cont` and calculate all the basics statistics? I was trying with a `for` loop but doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `select` to keep the columns in 'df1' and then with `summarise_each` get the basic statistics

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     select_(.dots = df_cont$variable.names) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean, sum)) #specify the functions
```

If 'variable.names' is `factor`, convert it to `character` (`select_(.dots = as.character(df_cont$variable.names))`)

In addition to passing functions individually in `summarise_each`, we can also call the `summary` to get the `min`, `max`, `median`, `mean` etc.

```
df1 %>% 
     select_(.dots = df_cont$variable.names) %>% 
     summary
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can do it by this way (only if you have all the continuos):

```
df1<-lapply(df1, as.numeric)
mean<-vapply(df1, mean, na.rm=TRUE, numeric(1))
median<-vapply(df1, median, na.rm=TRUE, numeric(1))
des<-vapply(df1,sd,na.rm=T,numeric(1))
var<-vapply(df1, var, na.rm=TRUE, numeric(1))
maxi<-vapply(df1, max, na.rm=TRUE, numeric(1))
min<-vapply(df1, min, na.rm=TRUE, numeric(1))

cont<-data.frame(mean,median,des,var,max,min)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
summary.df <- as.data.frame(summary(df1[df_cont$variable.names]))[,2:3]
names(summary.df) <- c('variable.name', 'stat')

   variable.name stat
1          me_cu Min.   : 300.0  
2          me_cu 1st Qu.: 397.5  
3          me_cu Median : 700.0  
4          me_cu Mean   :1123.8  
5          me_cu 3rd Qu.:1275.0  
6          me_cu Max.   :3400.0  
7        par_pri  Min.   : 50.0  
8        par_pri  1st Qu.: 75.0  
9        par_pri  Median :225.0  
10       par_pri  Mean   :323.8  
11       par_pri  3rd Qu.:487.5  
12       par_pri  Max.   :800.0
```

Comment: How can I do it when I don't know the colum's number?

Comment: you don't need to know the column's number, 2:3 is just used to discard the first column of the summary data frame which is not useful, it does not have anything to do with the column's number.